# Cassandra : setting row_cache_size_in_mb decrease performance by factor 4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In order to achieve better read performance with Cassandra, I switched the row cache setting from :

```
 row_cache_size_in_mb = 0
```

To :

```
 row_cache_size_in_mb = 2000
```

2 GB for the row cache sounds reasonnable to me regarding my configuration. So, I then reboot nodes, and I was surprised that such setting decrease my overall performance by factor 4. As an example, a query that just took 2 seconds, now took more than 8 seconds to complete.

I have then enabled tracing, and I see "Row cache hit". I also see that the row cache hit ratio is very high. So row caching seems to properly work with my data model. However, it clearly slow down my queries... Have you an idea why ?

**Update :**

I have made a new test. I keep the row cache on :

```
 row_cache_size_in_mb = 2000
```

I disable the row cache for the largest column familly (table) I have :

```
 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'
```

Now my queries work like before (took about 2 seconds). So, is the row cache only made to speed up queries for small column familly ?

Are there alternative to push data in cache for large column family ? What I'm expecting on large CF, is that if an user do a query, and then if it do immediately the same query again, then the non-first queries can return immediately because rows are already in memory.

Comment: how big is your heap? how big is your memtable size and keycache?

Comment: My heap is about 16GB. Total memory per node is 48GB. Key cache and memtables settings are turn to defaults. Could you please explain the relation ship between the heap and the row cache, because as far I know, the row cache is off-heap by default ? Thanks

Comment: Is your GC log reporting long pauses at all? `grep "stopped: [1-9]" *gc*.current | grep \`date +%m-%d\`T | sort -nk11`. The RowCacheKey copies the partition key into new byte array so when utilized a lot it can put a lot of pressure on YGCs if you have larger or composite keys.
Unrelated: might wanna set memtable_heap_space_in_mb to 1000. default will be 4gb or 1/4th heap which is a lot of fragmentation (if using default CMS) and makes flushes huge - not your problem here but its generally a good idea to cap it when heap gets larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that this is likely because your cassandra nodes are spending quite a bit of time evacuating the row cache and running Java GC cleanups.  Your best bet to isolate the issue is to use a tool (datadog, datastax ops center, Jconsole) to determine the frequency of minor and major GC.

Additionally if your queries are taking ~2 seconds I expect you're probably doing large range scans.  I tried using row cache for this in the past and it did not work well.

You might also try reducing your `rows_per_partition` on the tables that you're running row cache on.